# Salah's goal assisted by Alisson Becker was not offside why?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

Mo Salah's goal against Manchester United was not awarded offside.
Plz tell me why as I did not understand it clearly.

Comment: Insufficient detail in question. At least specify the game, ideally the time at which it happened. Or even better link to a video of it, or draw diagrams of who was where at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Salah was on Liverpools side when Alisson kicked the ball, offside can be when the receiving player is on the other teams half and if the other team doesn't have atleast 2 player behind him but yeah you can read the rules from E. Sommer's comment